# Definition of "Regime of selection"

Tags: evolution, terminology, population-biology, adaptation

How would you define `Regime of selection` (or `Selection regime`)?

In addition to a accurate definition, a developped example would be very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I'll kick this off with an attempt at a definition: a selection regime is

```
the set of selective pressures on a population
```

As in, "alteration of selection regime resulting from harvest" (Mooney & McGraw 2007)

or "Human-induced nutrient input can change the selection regime and lead to the loss of biodiversity. For example, eutrophication caused speciation reversal in polymorphic whitefish populations through a flattening of littoral–pelagic selection gradients." (Hirsch et al 2013)

- [**Hirsch PE, Eckmann R, Oppelt C, Behrmann-Godel J**. 2013. Phenotypic and genetic divergence within a single whitefish form - detecting the potential for future divergence. Evolutionary Applications 6: 1119–1132.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/eva.12087)
- [**Mooney E, McGraw J**. 2007. Alteration of selection regime resulting from harvest of American ginseng, Panax quinquefolius. Conserv Genet 8: 57–67.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10592-006-9148-3)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer so far I found is this one (see Baum and Larson 1991):

> The criterion of historical genesis is applied using the concept of
> "selective regime," the aggregation of organismal and environmental
> factors that combine to determine the expected action of natural
> selection on actual and potential character variation.

[Baum, D. A., and A. Larson. 1991. Adaptation reviewed: a phylogenetic methodology for studying character macroevolution. Systematic biology 40:1.](http://www.botany.wisc.edu/courses/botany_940/15Stebbins/Baum%201991%20Systematic%20Zoology.pdf)

In this article you can find this example:

> For example, the hypothesis that a given floral trait is an adaptation
> enhancing the efficiency of bird-pollination would be tested by
> scoring subject taxa as having either the selective regime
> "bird-pollinated" or an alternative one (e.g., "insect-pollinated").

Then, you would be able to determine part of the selective regime of the floral trait. I say part of it because it's almost impossible to know all the abiotic  and biotic factors that can trigger a change in a trait variation.

Hope that helps.